# UIButton in UIView Want to call isHidden in a func in ViewController

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uibutton, swift4

I created a UIButton in a NIB ( UIView : A TableViewCell  ). I want to be able to control its isHidden property in a function, in the master TableViewController

How would I call that button in the function?

Would I make the function when I call cellForRowAt ?

What I really want to achieve:  This is for a demo purpose so the code doesn't have to be secure

Use Case :

by default in the tableCell, you see the button, but, when the function is called, the button is hidden. and IF possible, the Cell shrinks accordingly..if that's too difficult, don't worry about that.

Thanks!

Comment: When do you wan the button hidden? More precisely when are you calling the function that is supposed to hide your button?

Comment: The function that I call will hide the button. the function will do other processes. I call the function only when I want to show the change in the UI, since this is a demo, the function would be called in viewdidload. I would comment the function out, when I don't want the button hidden, and uncomment when I want the button hidden.  It's not permanent code.

Comment: Ok. I will rephrase. Where will you call this function?

Comment: The function is really just a test case lets say, Once I show the UI changes, the function will be removed from code. Actual API / JSON calls will later change the UI...Just need a func to mock the button isHidden property. But the button is in one UIView class and the func needs to be in another class. Do I  shared instance the button?

Comment: Share you cell class. If you know the indexpath of the cell where your button is then you can get the cell from that indexpath and set the button hidden.

Comment: Oh that easy?! I reference the UIView class, in the indexPath ( index 0 in my case ) and call it there? I just need to reference the class correctly.